# Why I'm gettingUncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. using this draggable code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using this code from Web Dev Simplified:

JS:

```
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable')
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.drag-container')

draggables.forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
        draggable.classList.add('dragging')
    })

    draggable.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
        draggable.classList.remove('dragging')
    })
})

containers.forEach(container => {
    container.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY)
        const draggable = document.querySelector('.dragging')
        if (afterElement == null) {
            container.appendChild(draggable)
        } else {
            container.insertBefore(draggable, afterElement)
        }
    })
})

function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
    const draggableElements = [...container.querySelectorAll('.draggable:not(.dragging)')]

    return draggableElements.reduce((closest, child) => {
        const box = child.getBoundingClientRect()
        const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2
        if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
            return { offset: offset, element: child }
        } else {
            return closest
        }
    }, { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }).element
}
```

CSS:

```
.drag-container {
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.draggable {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: move;
}

    .draggable.dragging {
        opacity: .5;
    }
```

Spending too much time with C# for the backend, I've found myself strugling with some frontend JS, and then just copied the code above.

But I can't make it work on my code. My code has this other code doing the preview of the images going to be uploaded:

```
function previewImages() {

    let aux = document.getElementById("preview-multiple");

    if (aux.hasChildNodes()) {

    while (aux.firstChild) {
        aux.removeChild(aux.firstChild);
        }

    }


    if (this.files) {
        [].forEach.call(this.files, readAndPreview);
    }

    function readAndPreview(file) {

        if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
            return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
        } 

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var image = new Image();
            image.height = 100;
            image.title = file.name;
            image.src = this.result;
            image.className = "draggable";
            image.draggable = true;
            //draggable.js dependent of previewImage.js
            aux.appendChild(div);
            div.appendChild(image)
        });

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }

}
```

In this code I wrote :

```
image.className = "draggable";
            image.draggable = true;
```

for it to be draggable. And also wraped it into divs for better organization.

But I'm getting this errors when trying to drag:

[image]

I don't really know where I'm failing.

The next step will be storing the images in the database with ordering coming from the `View`, but that's another future problem.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. The problem was the script was being runned before the images got inserted in the DOM.